# ionic-platform-web-client Fail then fixed then fails again

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, command-line-interface, bower

Nevermind that I got this to install successfully. The issue now is that after I managed to fix it and install it.. Later on it fails again. I can't seem to understand what this has to do with..

1. Running this command on our existing ionic project renders the error below.

   `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client`

*Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.14)
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Version: 1.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.3
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175*

So I went ahead and pretty much uninstalled everything from the npm, bower, node, ionic, the platforms.. Wiped out the the project from the top to the bottom and IT WORKED!! `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client` installs!

**BUT then**

After sometime.. Whenever I come back to the project and run other commands like, `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` it fails again. Its very confusing. Does anyone know where the issue stems from?

Answer (score 1):

`ionic add <component name>` runs `bower install --save-dev <component name>`. See these lines:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/3d675b1584b5921ca05aad6af17d84fd691e7b0c/lib/ionic/add.js#L16-L30
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/3d675b1584b5921ca05aad6af17d84fd691e7b0c/lib/ionic/add.js#L78-L82

Try to running:
`bower install --loglevel=debug ionic-platform-web-client` and see if you get any glimpse on the issue.